# How to store the actual underlying DB value in a combobox while displaying a more user-friendly value?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I need to display values like "Surreptitiously" and "Discreetly" in a comboBox but thereafter be able to set the comboboxes' SelectedItem based on the underlying DB values for those words (e.g., "S" and "D").

I reckon I can use the comboBoxes' DisplayMember and ValueMember properties for this somehow, but can I subsequently do something analagous to the following with the actual (valuemember) values:

```
comboBoxAdverbs.SelectedIndex = comboBoxAdverbs.Items.IndexOf(weirdAdverbs[CURRENT_ADVERB]);
```

As "weirdAdverbs[CURRENT_ADVERB]" contains the values like "S" and "D" it, of course, doesn't find and set the SelectedIndex when the comboBox contains the values "Surreptitiously" and "Discreetly"

If I set the combobox Item Tag value to "S" and "D" (assuming that's possible), I can loop through those values, but I'm hoping there's a one-line way of doing it similar to the "IndexOf()" above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found that works for me is to store the selectedindex value, after it's set, into the combobox's Tag property. Then, if the user attempts to change the selectedIndex when it is supposed to be in a "readonly" state, simply change it back to the selectedIndex value stored in the Tag property:

```
comboBoxPlatypusId.SelectedIndex = comboBoxPlatypusId.Items.IndexOf(DuckbillVals[Duckbill_PlatypusID]);
comboBoxPlatypusId.Tag = comboBoxPlatypusId.SelectedIndex;
...
private void comboBoxFunnyMammals_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var cb = sender as ComboBox;
    if (cb != null)
    {
        int validSelection = Convert.ToInt32(cb.Tag);
        if (cb.SelectedIndex != validSelection) {
            cb.SelectedIndex = validSelection;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use a template class for this and it comes in pretty darn handy. The combo box will show whatever text you want and you can store a value with it.

```
    public class cboItem<T>
{
    public cboItem(string name, T value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name == null ? "" : Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Combo box items can be anything, including classes/structs. By default it will use the ToString() implementation to display items, but if you populate a set of objects you can use DisplayMember and ValueMember to great effect.

As a simple example to give you some ideas we'll bind the combo box to a set of KeyValuePair instances for your weird verb codes and their descriptive names. Alternatively you can use linq to compose anonymous types, or create your own suitable classes/structs.

```
private void populateCombo()
{
    comboBoxAdverbs.Items.Clear();
    comboBoxAdverbs.Items.Add( new Tuple<string, string>( "S", "Surreptitiously" ) );
    comboBoxAdverbs.Items.Add( new Tuple<string, string>( "D", "Discreetly" ) );
    comboBoxAdverbs.DisplayMember = "Item2";
}
```

Then in your code where you want to select an item matching a provided code: (I.e. "D")

```
var item = comboBoxAdverbs.Items
    .OfType<Tuple<string,string>>()
    .FirstOrDefault(i => string.Compare(i.Item1, textBox1.Text, true) == 0);

if (item != null)
    comboBoxAdverbs.SelectedItem = item;
```

This attempts to find the matching item by comparing the key against whatever input (in this case a textbox value) and if it finds a match, sets the SelectedItem to tell the combo box to select it.

** Edit: Whups, had originally use KeyValuePair which I didn't realize was a struct so no Null check-ability. Changed to Tuple (Essentially Pair)